# How do I get cam slings replaced?

Tags: gear, climbing, maintenance, trad-climbing, camming-devices

I bought my first set of [cams](http://dmmclimbing.com/products/dragon-cams/) and I've been curious about what happens when the slings start to wear out. Are they user-replaceable? The ones I purchased seem to be very un-user-replaceable:

[image: DMM dragon cams]

How do I get cam slings replaced?

Comment: It's also common for the wires to get frayed, and there are cheap repair kits you can send away for. You need to be careful to get the right one, though; Camalot C4s have gone through a long series of redesigns over the years.

Comment: Related [What accreditations should a professional rock climbing cams reslinger have?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10875/what-accreditations-should-a-professional-rock-climbing-cams-reslinger-have)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are user replaceable, in fact [some manufacturers recommend replacing slings every 2-5 years if they're very frequently used](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/qc-labreslinging-camalots-and-c3s.html), but they're only user replaceable if you know how to sew structural climbing gear and have the equipment to bartack a loop of SuperTape or 10mm Dynex.

The simplest thing to do is simply replace the worn sling with 1" tube webbing, which obviously wouldn't work for the cam shown above in the question, in which case I'd recommend using 7 or 8mm accessory cord (the bigger the better) tied with a double fishermans. Other than that, you may be able to send your cams back to the manufacturer for re-slinging, many manufacturers such as Black Diamond for example have [re-slinging services](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/climbing%2Fspare-parts-BD0998020000ALLS.html) for their cams that pretty affordable, your other option would be to find a climbing store that has the equipment to re-sling your cams for you.

Take time to consider too when your slings wear out if it may be time to retire your cams, all safety gear has a lifecycle, and should be retired at the end of it. When in doubt, throw it out.

Answer (score 6):

The information you need is on the manufacturers [website](http://dmmclimbing.com/about/servicing-repairs/).

> We offer servicing for DMM Cams (trigger wires and slings), and Torque Nuts (slings) if they pass a quality inspection. Prior to sending them to us, we ask you to inspect and assess your gear in accordance to the supplied user instructions and inspection criteria.

for others considering replacing their own slings [Black diamond](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en/qc-labthe-dangers-of-modifying-your-gear.html) has compiled some of the common problems people encounter.