# What accreditations should a professional rock climbing cams reslinger have?

Tags: rock-climbing, maintenance, camming-devices

Rock climbing cams often have integrated slings. Like all webbing, these slings can be degraded by UV and wear out much sooner than the cam themselves. There are numerous companies that will "professionally" resling cams.

One of the advantages of reslinging a cam professionally is the loop of the sling will closed with a bartack (as opposed to knotted). While sewing machines capable of bartacking are not cheap, anyone can buy one. Is there some sort of accreditation that one should look for in a cam reslinger?

Comment: Why not just have the manufacturer do it?

Comment: I don't think any exist.

Comment: @BenCrowell the manufacturer is not in the same country as me and I cannot find a link on their webpage that says they resling gear. Further, in my case the cams (rigid friends) are discontinued which might make it more difficult.

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/how-do-i-get-cam-slings-replaced

Comment: @ShemSeger not sure how I missed that one. I think this one is a little different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a UIAA certification for slings just as is there are for (nearly?) all critical recreational climbing gear.  You should only have reslinging done by a company that produces UIAA certified climbing softgoods.

Certification logo: [image]

[image]

http://www.theuiaa.org/upload_area/Safety/Standards/Safety-Standards/UIAA_104_Slings_March_2013.pdf

Comment: Hi Mr. Wizard. That link is leading me to a Page Not Found. It's still the UIAA website though, so maybe they just moved it. If you want to check it out, that would be great!

Comment: @Sue Do you have the updated URL?  It would save me having to search for it.